# Google Search Results show and extra 0 in my title

Tags: google-search, title

The search results for my site have an added 0 in front of the title. Whereas in my title on my page it does not have any such thing in the title. Can somebody point me in the right direction of how to look into this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **0** from the thumbs up/down section is within the H2 that contains your page title.

[image: H2 tag]

Pull that out of there and keep *just* your page title in the heading tag. That should help search engines identify the actual page title. I'd also suggest you use H1 there instead of H2.